# IIS Cross Origin Issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis

I have a MongoDB server up and running and another server running Express and a react app through IIS. I have enabled Cross Origin through IIS but still have no luck pulling information from my database on any computer other then the server its running on. The Error I get is : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ... (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Again I have 0 issue getting to the website and using all function on the server IIS is on but when I use a local machine I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your express server is throwing a CORS error. you can use the "cors" module at node serves and configure IIS at cors origin. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: If configuring IIS still does not work, then set cors origin to "*".

Comment: How to set it in IIS ? Could you please share a screen shot ?